# Trying To Run a VM On Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I cant seem to run a VM on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, virtual box is reporting "Failed to load VMMR0.r0 (VERR_SUPLIB_WORLD_WRITEABLE)." [image]

I have tried all the fixes I could see on the bug reporting page of virtual box and nothing is working. I am also willing to go with an alternative but I can not seem to get vmware to compile its virtual network driver and load it into the kernel and I don't have a CD or flash drive to use for xen, I'm not experienced with VM's and I am only doing some experimenting. Does anyone know either what to do about this error with virtual box, or have an alternative quick suggestion?

Comment: Have you installed more Virtualbox VMs on this machine? Have you tried to install a second VM? You could delete (or better rename) the .virtualbox folders in your home folder and start over. Please give more info about what you tried to fix this!

Comment: @SPRBRN I have tried to give permissions as the described fix to various folders such as `/usr/lib` in various combinations with deleting the VM and starting over and several times re installing virtual box and at least once doing a complete cleanout of all vbox files. I have tried to boot the VM with diiferent settings including memory, vram, and weather or not I want to boot it as a live cd. I have noticed that there does not even have to be a OS image attached the for it the error to occur: I tried to just see what would happen if I tried to boot arch (to see if images came with it).

Comment: @SPRBRN right now and I'm trying to do a Ubuntu - 64 bit server image.